# Seperate fields for date and time in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, sqldatatypes

I am creating a table in mysql where I want to store 'date of birth' and 'time of birth' as 2 separate fields.
What data types I have to use to create these 2 columns in mysql?

Comment: Use `DATETIME` datatype and one column..

Comment: why you need  two columns ??  .. you could use a single DATETIME column and retrieve the part you need  with mysql select functions

Comment: DATE and DATETIME

Comment: Also  `DATETIME` (5 bytes) needs 1 bytes less storage space vs `DATE` (3 bytes) and `TIME` (3 bytes)  assuming you are using a MySQL version later then MySQL 5.6.4.. Then you save ~10Mb diskspace per 1 million records nice if you use SSD instead off a normal HDD

Comment: "`DATE` and `DATETIME`" @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy is wrong the datetypes are `DATE` and `TIME`.. But topicstarter check mine other comment

Answer (score 1):

There are two data types DATE and Time that will help you. Here is an example:

```
   CREATE TABLE table (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    birth_date DATE,
    birth_time TIME
    );
```